# Previous fragment element is still active after adding new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

My question might be described much more better with this image. When I am adding second fragment(2nd image) over first fragment (1st image) first fragment element(Spinner, EditText) are still active.Active mean touching on the same place I can see the dropdown is coming down.

I can't replace the fragment because I need to go back in the same state where user left the first fragment.Can any one tell me what's the problem.

I am adding the second fragment using a broadcast because it need to call from a baseAdapter listview.Code is like this.

**ListView onclick**

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Log.v("TAG", "Clicked: " + itemListPogo.get(position).getitemIdplato());

            Intent i = new Intent("start.fragment.action");
            i.putExtra("plateId", itemListPogo.get(position).getitemIdplato());
            mContext.sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    });
```

**Reveiving**

```
    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String plateId = extra.getString("plateId");  

            Fragment fragment = new PlateDetailsFragment(DashBoardActivity.this, Integer.parseInt(plateId));
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = (DashBoardActivity.this).getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack("back", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(plateId).commit();
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("start.fragment.action"));
```

[image: First two pic is first two fragment 3rd image is having the problem]

Comment: "I can't replace the fragment because I need to go back in the same state where user left the first fragment" -- you seem to be removing the old fragment via `popBackStack()`, so I do not understand this comment. "I am adding the second fragment using a broadcast because it need to call from a baseAdapter listview" -- **please** do not use system broadcasts for this. Use an in-process event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.). As it stands, anyone can hack your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple trick for this. Take the main container/ the parent view of your top fragment and add an `onClickListener` for it. Don't do anything inside onClick. This way your fragment on the top will capture the user clicks. Hope it was clear enough.

Example - If your fragment's layout has a `Linearlayout` as the parent, assign an `onClickListener` for it in your fragment code the same way you do for a button.

Comment: Yes you are right. Can u tell me why it's happening is it a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, the fragment registers clicks for only those elements which have an onClickListener. Otherwise the clicks are sent to the element behind the fragment. I think the reason is that a fragment only returns a view and is not a completely separate screen.

Comment: How to apply the same with a ViewPager ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove previous fragment.

Try to use this code:

```
public static void insertFragment(Context context, int resId, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz, Bundle args, boolean stack)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            FragmentManager manager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tx = manager.beginTransaction();

            if (stack)
            {
                tx.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            else
            {
                Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById(resId);
                if (fragment != null)
                    tx.remove(fragment);
            }
            tx.add(resId, Fragment.instantiate(context, clazz.getName(), args));
            tx.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I need the previous fragment in same state I mean there is a dropdown as you can see based on that dropdown it going to prepare the list.So if I am going to remove the previous fragment at the time of coming back I can't get back that same state of that list.